# Spring Boot - @SQSListener and @SpyBean are not working together?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, amazon-sqs

I have a simple spring boot application with AWS SQS integration.
In integration tests I tried to spy on method annotated with @SqsListener annotation and got a behavior where bean *sometimes* wasn't spied.

You can take a look at sample project here: https://github.com/Sanych/aws-sqs-spybean-troubleshooting

run `mvn clean verify`

In this log one may notice, that 2 out of 3 test method were spied successfully:

```
2020-09-06 15:39:23.597  INFO 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : Started SQSListenerIT in 0.813 seconds (JVM running for 24.024)
2020-09-06 15:39:23.604  WARN 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : calling class com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener$MockitoMock$1506819983
2020-09-06 15:39:23.604  WARN 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : sendMessage to queue: test 1
2020-09-06 15:39:23.810  WARN 18372 --- [enerContainer-2] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener            : id: class com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener$MockitoMock$1506819983, received: 'test 1'
2020-09-06 15:39:23.929  WARN 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : calling class com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener$MockitoMock$1506819983
2020-09-06 15:39:23.929  WARN 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : sendMessage to queue: test 2
2020-09-06 15:39:24.052  WARN 18372 --- [enerContainer-2] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener            : id: class com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener, received: 'test 2'
2020-09-06 15:39:29.148  WARN 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : calling class com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener$MockitoMock$1506819983
2020-09-06 15:39:29.148  WARN 18372 --- [           main] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT          : sendMessage to queue: test 3
2020-09-06 15:39:29.175  WARN 18372 --- [enerContainer-2] com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener            : id: class com.aws.test.demo.SQSListener$MockitoMock$1506819983, received: 'test 3'
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.468 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT
[ERROR] test2  Time elapsed: 5.218 s  <<< ERROR!
org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException:
Assertion condition defined as a lambda expression in com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT
Wanted but not invoked:
SQSListener.listen(<any string>);
-> at com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT.lambda$sendMessageFromFileAndWaitForListenerToRead$0(SQSListenerIT.java:57)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
 within 5 seconds.
        at com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT.sendMessageFromFileAndWaitForListenerToRead(SQSListenerIT.java:57)
        at com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT.test2(SQSListenerIT.java:42)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked:

Wanted but not invoked:
SQSListener.listen(<any string>);
-> at com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT.lambda$sendMessageFromFileAndWaitForListenerToRead$0(SQSListenerIT.java:57)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
        at com.aws.test.demo.SQSListenerIT.lambda$sendMessageFromFileAndWaitForListenerToRead$0(SQSListenerIT.java:57)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess from your log, SQSListener is not trigger. Not invoked mean you wait for a time but it is not invoked. Can you share your test?

Comment: Also you don't need to test sqs listener because you are testing annotation. You can write unit test but IT is a little bit strange. For each IT test you need yo pay price :)

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez code sample is in git repo https://github.com/Sanych/aws-sqs-spybean-troubleshooting

Comment: I faced a very similar issue. Did you manage to find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into exactly the same problem.

From the `SpyBean`documentation:

> All beans in the context of the same type will be wrapped with the spy.

After thorough investigation, the only reasonable explanation for me is that the `SqsListener` method / bean is registered **before** the `MockitoPostProcessor` actually wraps the existing Bean with a spy proxy.

As a result, the "real" bean will actually be invoked but this invocation cannot be validated with `verify(...)` because the invocation is not triggered through the Spy proxy.

Might be good to know: the `@SqsListener` methods are registered via the `QueueMessageHandler`, which is constructed by the `SqsAutoConfiguration`. Hence if the `SqsAutoConfiguration` runs before the `MockitoPostProcessor` wrapped the spy bean, the invocation does not go through the Spy proxy.

**Possible solution**

I used following approach to work around this problem..

```
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    @SqsListener("queue")
    public void listen(@NotificationMessage Event event) {
        oterService.doWork();
    }

}
```

- Split unit tests (testing `MyService` functionally) from integration tests (**only** testing that `MyService#listen` is actually invoked)
- In integration tests (`@SpringBootTest`): don't `@SpyBean` the listener bean itself, but a bean used by the listener. (`OtherService` in my example)
- `verify(otherService, timeout(500)).doWork()`

Although this answer is rather abstract, I hope this can be of any help.

EDIT:
Just mocking `OtherService` using `MockBean` doesn't suffice. I had to explicitly create a `OtherService` mock (`mock(OtherService.class`) and set it in my `MyService` using a package private setter.
I admit, not the cleanest solution, however so far this is the only solution that worked for me.

EDIT (2022-02-16):
As of Spring Cloud AWS 2.4, an `@SqsTest` annotation is available for exactly this purpose:
https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/releases/tag/v2.4.0
https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/v2.4.0/spring-cloud-aws-samples/spring-cloud-aws-sqs-sample/src/test/java/io/awspring/cloud/sqs/sample/SqsSampleApplicationTests.java